# How to Bulk Change Source Links?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Trying to change the Excel source file for charts and objects linked in a PowerPoint deck.

I found this:

```vb
Sub ChangeOLELinks()

    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim sOldPath As String
    Dim sNewPath As String
  
    ' EDIT THIS TO REFLECT THE PATHS YOU WANT TO CHANGE
    sOldPath = InputBox("Enter Old Project ie: \Development\", "Old Path") 
    sNewPath = InputBox("Enter New Project ie: \Test\", "New Path") 
     
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSld.Shapes
            If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            
                Dim stringPath   As String
                stringPath = Replace(oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, sOldPath, sNewPath, 1, , vbTextCompare)
               
                oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = stringPath
               ' set update mode to auto and update then set it back to manual
                oSh.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionAutomatic
                oSh.LinkFormat.Update
                oSh.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionManual
                               
            End If
        Next oSh
    Next oSld
    ActivePresentation.Save

    MsgBox ("Done!")
    
NormalExit:
    Exit Sub
        
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox ("Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
    Resume NormalExit
    
End Sub
```

This works for OLE objects/links. It isn't updating any of the linked charts.

How can I include charts?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "linked charts" if they're not OLE linked objects?  If you mean PPT charts that have had data paste/linked into them, then as far as I know there's no access to the link other than one property that tells you "The data's linked"

Comment: Yeah I solved this by inserting all the charts as linked objects rather than pasting as charts, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As your charts are paste-linked (4th option) from Excel, they're of msoChart type.
The `LinkFormat.SourceFullName` property **works for this type too** so you just have to replace your

```
If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject
```

with

```
if oSh.Type = msoChart
```

Comment: This gives an error though that `LinkFormat.SourceFullName: Invalid request. This operation requires a linked onject.`